# convert momentary switch to toggle switch using 555

Tags: switches, toggle-switch, 555

[image]

this circuit diagram is used to convert a momentary switch to toggle function , how can i extend the diagram to get three output stats to switch between two LEDs and an off state if it possible

Comment: Use a microcontroller. Simpler.

Comment: can you explain what output states you need? it seems that with 2 LEDs you should be able to get 4 states, not three.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to extend the toggle circuit to three states. Instead, use the 555 to debounce the pushbutton, and then use its output to clock a three-state FSM comprising a pair of DFFs and a NOR gate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fipaHL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>