# How to convert an interrupt signal to toggle a continous signal

Tags: digital-logic, signal-processing

I am working on a project where a momentary contact micro switch is used to activate the Vdd pin of a 555timer IC - [Datasheet [Link]](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/TLC555). Thus, I need to toggle the Vdd pin every time a micro switch is pressed. In essence, every switch press toggles the IC from ON to OFF or vice versa. The current requirement of the Vdd pin is less than 1 mA only and the working voltage is 12V. The circuit looks somewhat as follows -
[image]

There is no micro-controller or ADC on board which makes things a little complex. Switch details - [Link](https://tech.alpsalpine.com/e/products/detail/SKTQAAE010/)

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and clarify by [edit]ing your question. Please do not answer in comments, this is not a forum. -- What is the switch shown in your schematic, is this the momentary micro switch? -- What did your web research on "555 toggle flip-flop" reveal, and why did it not help you?

Comment: Do you have to toggle VDD, or can you instead just toggle the reset pin of the 555. This would inhibit the output.

Comment: You could [use another 555](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/504509/11683).

Comment: Simplest solution involves no extra electronics at all - just use a toggle switch instead of a momentary action switch.

Comment: @brhans There is some space constraint issue with using the toggle switch as toggle switches are much taller compared to momentary switches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be a DFF:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2gMyO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Every time a rising edge (this is important so the DFF should be of a rising-edge or high-level triggered one) is seen on the CLK pin the output will be the inverse (NOT) of the current output state, hence D = \Q.

R1 keeps the CLK input at 0 when there's no input applied. R1-R2-C1 network helps to filter out switch bounce.

- If you can find a DFF that works with 12V (I haven't checked) then all you need is a post totem pole buffer to increase the current output capability *(**NOTE:** you said the current requirement is less than 1 mA, but the presence of the 68n capacitor across the 555's supply rail increases the initial peak current demand)*:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9ue9e.png)</sup>

- If you can't then you'll need a voltage level translator instead, like the one following (you don't need the post totem pole driver above):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl4g8N.png)</sup>

Comment: Any high-voltage CMOS logic ought to work off 12 V.